# Ionic social login using platform-browser and i am try to use openfb in my project how to use?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I making ionic app in which i am using socialite login when click to login with facebook or google-plus then its gives error that cordova not available. In backen i am using laravel-passport for authenetication .How to resolve this problem please help me.....

login.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController, ToastController, 
    AlertController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../user';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';

import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  public onLoginForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public menuCtrl: MenuController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService,
    private nativeStorage: NativeStorage,
    private googlePlus: GooglePlus,
    private fb: Facebook,
    public router: Router) {

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.onLoginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'email': [null, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])],
      'password': [null, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')
      ])]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {

    //console.log(this.onLoginForm.value);
    this.userService.login(this.onLoginForm.get('email').value, this.onLoginForm.get('password').value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        async data => {

          if (data['error'] == 'Unauthorised.') {
            //console.log('Unauthorised');
            const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'Please enter valid Email Or Password.',
              duration: 3000
            });
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            toast.present();
          }
          else {

            const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'You have successfully logged in.',
              duration: 3000
            });
           // this.router.navigate(['/start']);
           this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/app/tabs/tab1');
            toast.present();
          }
        }
      );
  }

  async doGoogleLogin(){
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Please wait...'
    });
    //this.presentLoading(loading);

    this.googlePlus.login({
      'scopes': '', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
      'webClientId': '456961607151-r2kjrs0k5qnk7r40auuvv5idndafmpqv.apps.googleusercontent.com', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
      'offline': true // Optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server
    })
    .then(user =>{
      loading.dismiss();

      this.nativeStorage.setItem('google_user', {
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        //picture: user.imageUrl
      })
      .then(() =>{
        this.router.navigate(["/user"]);
      }, error =>{
        console.log(error);
      })
      loading.dismiss();
    }, err =>{
      console.log(err)
      loading.dismiss();
    });


  }
  doFacebookLogin(){
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
    .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
    .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));

  }
}
```

In login.page.html myfunction is declear for socialite login.

login.page.html

```
 <ion-grid class="btn-group">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="4">
            <ion-button shape="round" (click)="doFacebookLogin()" expand="full" color="secondary">
              <ion-icon  name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="4">
            <ion-button shape="round" expand="full" color="secondary">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="4">
            <ion-button  (click)="doGoogleLogin()" shape="round" expand="full" color="secondary">
              <ion-icon  name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing this in the browser or mobile. In browser, cordova native features won't work and it will display error "cordova is not found".

As per the Ionic Docs, below cordova plugins are installed

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid --variable WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID=mywebapplicationclientid
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Comment: How to check cordova in browser...@Suresh Kumar Ariya

Comment: Cordova will not work in browser. are you creating application for mobile or desktop?

Comment: i am creating for mobile but want to check in desktop

Comment: well you can (and should) run cordova in browser to be able to test cordova related features using either `ionic serve --ssl --cordova --platform browser` or `ng run app:ionic-cordova-serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100 --ssl --platform=browser` (`--ssl` is a bonus for facebook login to work ;)

Comment: @ciekawy : If only I could upvote you comment a million times! I have seen thousands of comments out there saying, oh, this will only work on a device. Well, then what's the point of using ionic to "speed up development" if you cannot see your changes in a browser?? Having an emulator up and running is not always possible on every device, not to mention having to wait for a few minutes for a full build on android or IOS. Thanks a lot!